# How to write aws-sdk-cpp[s3] in manifest .vcpkg dependency file for cmake?

Tags: cmake, dependencies, vcpkg

I am getting a strange error in in my cmake project in which the dependency I am trying to require does not work. In my vcpkg.json file, I have the following:

```
{
    "name": "glmcmake",
    "version-string": "1.0.0",
    "dependencies": [
        "aws-sdk-cpp[s3]"
    ]
}
```

However, when I run cmake I get the following error in the vcpkg-manifests-install.txt file:

```
$.dependencies[0] (a dependency): must be lowercase alphanumeric+hyphens, split with periods, and not reservedExtended documentation available at 'https://github.com/Microsoft/vcpkg/tree/master/docs/users/manifests.md'.
```

How do I write the aws-sdk-cpp[s3] dependency in the vcpkg.json file correctly so that it can download the right one? I do not need the entire aws-sdk-cpp library. I only need the s3 subfolder, basically.

When I search for aws-sdk-cpp on vcpkg, I can see the [s3] subfolder in particular, but I cannot get my cmake to agree with the way it is written on vcpkg search.

Any thoughts?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The solution is:

1. Specify the entire dependency as an object;
2. disable `default-features`, since you said

   > I do not need the entire aws-sdk-cpp library
3. list the features you *do* need—in this case, `s3` is a feature.

To illustrate:

```json
{
  "name": "aws-sdk-cpp",
  "default-features": false,
  "features": [
    "s3"
  ]
}
```

This will download exactly the feature (and its transitive dependencies), and nothing else. Refer to the [vcpkg documentation on the `features` field in Manifest mode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/vcpkg/users/manifests#features), and [this example using LLVM](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vcpkg/users/examples/selecting-llvm-features).

I'm not sure how useful this answer will be to *you* personally after nearly a year, but I'm hoping it might be useful to someone else.